# SelectNodes not pulling all child nodes correctly

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get a list of products from a webpage. I am using the url below to test my application but it is only pulling 10 of the 40 items. I have been digging around in the debugger and looking at the child nodes, it shows the first 10 as li items and the other 30 as divs. When I look at the inner text of the items showing up as divs it is completely empty. When looking at the html of the webpage all 40 items are listed as li items. Does anyone know why this is happening? All I need it to do is show all 40 items correctly as I can only see the first 10 right now.

```
//Create URL
var url = "https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=apples";
var itemTweak = itemTextBox.Text.Replace(" ", "%20");
url += itemTweak;
//Creates a client for the webpage
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

//Allow information to be parsed
var htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

//Grabs everything inside the list
var ProductsHtml = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='search-result-gridview-items four-items']").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be because some of the data is loaded using Javascript on the browser side.

If you look at the `html` all the products are in a json object in `<script id="searchContent" type="application/json">`

Maybe you should parse them from there like this:

```
var json = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script[@id='searchContent']");
//need Json.net for this to work...
JObject.Parse(json.InnerText)["searchContent"]["preso"]["items"];
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! It even separated everything out easier for me to find.Thanks man I really appreciate it. How did you know what to enter in for those parameters?

Comment: @Mr.Finch - This was a good question and I got confused for quite a while too... Anyhow once I found the json in the html, I just used LinqPad to drill down the object. You probably already know but there are ways to convert these into strongly typed C# objects now... This is a good starting point: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToObjectComplex.htm

Comment: I actually just started working with json today so that helps me out a ton. I did not know you could use this without an api, or maybe this is an api and I just did not know.